# How do you show the area bounded between $f\left(x\right)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}$,$g\left(x\right)=2x+1$, the x-axis and $x=2$ is $4 + 2e^{-1}$

Tags: integration

When I draw it out, I get that the area is equal to a triangle plus $\int_0^2 e^{ -\frac{x}{2}} dx$.

So $\frac{1}{4} + 2(1-\frac{1}{e}) $

Where does the $4$ come from?

Comment: Can someone help with LaTeX as well? Why isn't the second equation showing properly?Edit: nevermind i fixed it up

Comment: How did you get the upper limit of $x=2$?

Comment: oh sorry, it should be $x = 2$ as well

Comment: That is wrong. While the question says $y=0$ ($x-$axis) as one of the bounds, its answer is taking the area bound above the curve $f(x)$.

Comment: Ah I see. It must've been a misprint for something. So I am right if it is below the curve